# ggplot2 figure size with RMarkdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, markdown, r-markdown

My converting the R script (.R) into an `RMarkdown` file (.rmd) in RStudio and then pressing “knit html” result in two output files (that is, .html and .md files).  I am confronting 2 issues:

The `html` file shows that the title of the `ggplot` graph gets chopped. I have changed the original width of 11 to a new width of 15:

```
ggsave(file=outFile, width=15, height=7)
```

*How would I resolve the issue ? And how would I convert the .md file into a PDF file ?*

Answer (score 27):

Your question is not exactly clear. I'm not sure, for example, why you are using `ggsave()` to begin with. You can directly create a "ggplot" image in your file to `knit` and set your figure width and height in your input file.

In a ".Rmd" file, your code might look something like:

````
```{r fig.width=7, fig.height=4, echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars)
```
````

The `echo=FALSE` will make it so that the code doesn't display, but the resulting plot will. The figure width and height have been set with the relevant arguments.

If you wanted to convert your resulting markdown file to PDF, I would recommend looking at [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/index.html) which will allow you to do something like the following to convert your file to a PDF:

```
pandoc infile.md -o outfile.pdf
```

Alternatively, you can use R Sweave instead of R Markdown in R/RStudio. For instance, if you create a new "Rnw" file in RStudio and paste the following in, you'll have the option to directly compile a PDF instead of compile an HTML.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<fig.width=5, fig.height=3, echo=FALSE>>=
library(ggplot2)
qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars)
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: First issue:  I have resolved .. using the \n in the title. My R script involves (1) creating factors for ggplot and printing the results, and (2) writing functions that produce 5 geom bars and save them in 5 .png files.

Comment: @user1849365 I'm sorry, but without some sample script (please edit your question to show your data and and the relevant contents of your Rmd file), I'm not able to help you further. Were you ultimately able to generate a PDF?